# How can I prevent a string value from getting rounded when converted to a number value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, numbers

I have an input field that accepts numeric values. I'd like to find a method that converts that that string value into a number value.

**ParseInt()** was what first came to find, then **toFixed()**.

What do these have in common? It rounds the values to its Integer value (like ParseInt suggests--I know!).

How can I convert a string representation into a number value while retaining any decimal values?

ex:

```
"54.3" --> 54.3
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: try parseFloat().  parseInt() will only parse integer value.

Comment: How about parseFloat?

Comment: `+"54.3"` .................

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An integer is a whole number.

A Float is a number with decimal values.

Knowing this you will want to use `parseFloat()`, which will take the period into consideration; instead of `parseInt()` which will round to the nearest whole number.

Refer to: [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for more detailed information

### So the answer is:

`parseFloat("string");`

#### you can also do this which is known as a unary plus:

`let a = "54.3"`

`a = +a;`

Doing +a is practically the same as doing a * 1; it converts the value in `a` to a number if needed, but after that it doesn't change the value.

Comment: Why not the obvious `Number`? parseFloat prefers a radix argument and + is just a hacky way to do `Number("54.3")`

Comment: While this prevents rounding _to an integer_ (which was probably what the asker meant), I guess there will still be some (invisible) rounding due to the finite precision of the binary floating-point type used. With double-precision, the actual value will be close to `54.299999999999997` and as usual the _relative_ error is of the order of magnitude `10 ** -16`.

Comment: That's a great point @Jeppe. Rounding has been a computer shortcoming which has caused some interesting events, such as the patriot missile failure on February 25, 1991. Your point is one which should always be taken into consideration when implementing very accurate calculations.

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```js
//pass String as argument
var floatVal = parseFloat("54.3");
console.log(floatVal);
```

Comment: Or just use `a=>+a`.

Answer (score 4):

You can even use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) as a function to [numeric strings to a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Convert_numeric_strings_to_numbers):

```
Number("54.3") // 54.3
```

Note the following:

- `parseFloat` is supposed to *parse* a numeric value from a string and succeeds if beginning of string, if not all, is numeric.
- `Number` constructor or function checks if the entire string is numeric.
- `+"54.3"` is exactly the same as `Number("54.3")` behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an input field to a number as well as you can specify how many decimal values to retain.

So, supposing you are making your calculations with two decimal values but a user types an input of "3.14151617". you can use this method to convert the input and get rid of the extra decimal values.

`var input = "3.14151617"
 var num = +(parseFloat(input).toFixed(2))`